# Please explain the behavior of this code in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

I have wrote a code in javascript like

```
function onClic(){
    var i = 0;
    if ( i==2 ){
        var m = function(){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        var m = function(){
            return 2;
        }
    }
    alert(m());
}
```

the alert shows 2;

can you please explain me the behavior in this statement i.e. Why am I able to access m outside the If statement when I declared it inside If statement scope.
Also why is this working as ECMAScipt 5 specifies that we donot put the function declaration inside IF-ElSE block.

Comment: when onclic() is called, it declares `i to 0` so as per `if{}else{}` you have, `else` define the function `m()`, so by calling `m()` the definition in else part will get executed, so `2` is alerted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I able to access m outside the If statement when I declared it inside If statement scope.

Because JavaScript (ES5 at least, has only **function scope**, not block scope. The `if` statement *does not* create scope. Your code is equivalent to:

```
function onClic(){
    var i = 0;
    var m;  // m is "hoisted"
    if ( i==2 ){
        m = function(){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        m = function(){
            return 2;
        }
    }
    alert(m());
}
```

> Also why is this working as ECMAScipt 5 specifies that we donot put the function declaration inside IF-ElSE block.

Right, but what you have are function **expression**, not declarations. A function declaration is something like

```
function foo() { }
```

Function expressions can be put everywhere where an expression is valid to use.

While you are right that, according to the spec, function declarations cannot be used inside blocks, browser still allow it and actually produce different results. Run this in Firefox and Chrome:

```js
function foo() {
    alert(1);
}

if (false) {
    function foo() {
        alert(2);
    }
}

foo();
```

However, this will change in ES6 where this behavior will be properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable i is set to 0 at the start of your function. You never change it. You IF statement is testing if i is equal to 2; it isn't. So it jumps to the ELSE statement, and returns 2.

If you want it to do something, you never to change the value of i in some way that makes sense to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: sorry my mistake I should have asked question properly, actually I want to ask if my variable is inside the scope of If statement then how am I able to get its value outside the scope in the last round.

Comment: @AnkitAnand for this see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function onClic(){
var i = 0;// set i=0 
if ( i==2 ){   // so this condition always give false and control go to else statement
   var m = function(){
            return 1;
           }
}
else {
   var m = function(){ 
            return 2;
           }
}
alert(m());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw what you were actually asking.

The variable is still inside the onClic() function so it is still in the local scope even though it is within an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

- First you are checking for value of variable i in your function
- If condition check the value of i , if it is 2 it makes a function assignment to variable m the function returns 1
- if value of i is not 2 it makes a function assignment to variable m the function returns 2
- In the end you call m that return either 2 or 1.

> my variable is inside the scope of If statement then how am I able to
>   get its value outside the scope in the last round

The answer is in js you dont have block level scope , you have either global scope or local scope. Here I is local varaible so it can be accessed any where in this function